# How do you mount an ext2 formatted qemu disk image?

Tags: mount, qemu

I am having issues mounting an image I created with the `qemu-img` program. Every time I attempt to invoke mount upon the subsequent file, it responds with `failed to setup loop device: No such file or directory`.

It does not matter which user I invoke the following commands under, it continuously fails (su - or not).

```
$ qemu-img create flash.img 512M
$ mkfs.ext2 -L "FLASH001" flash.img
$ mount -t ext2 -o loop,rw flash.img /mnt/dfs/
```

---

Is there anything that I am missing? I have a typical Arch Linux install with all of the above commands installed from the Arch Linux repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the loop module loaded?
Try lsmod | grep loop and/or ls /dev/loop*

if this doesn't show anything, perhaps you need to do modprobe loop

Comment: `modprobe loop` returns nothing, `lsmod | grep loop` returns nothing; am I missing a loop driver? Could you point me in the direction of a package that could supply these things?

Comment: Aha! Apparently my kernel had updated without my knowledge, rendering any attempt to use the loop module futile. I appreciate your assistance with this.